# Logcheck: wildcards which include non-latin characters

Tags: logging, log-files, grep, regex, unicode

On my mail server, I have a custom logcheck rule as follows, which is intended to filter messages from deliver:

```
^\w{3} [ :0-9]{11} [._[:alnum:]-]+ deliver\.*\): msgid=.*: saved mail to.*$
```

Unfortunately, the msgid=.* wildcard does not match if there are non-latin characters in the Message-Id, so lines like the following make it through the filter:

```
May 10 19:43:20 zapp deliver(matt): msgid=<20110510064307.3702.qmail@ÇöÀÌ01>: saved mail to spam
```

Logcheck uses egrep internally, and I've not found any way to make the period character include non-latin characters. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not locale chars. To me part with `deliver\.*\):` seems wrong and it wouldn't match `deliver(matt)`. Try using `deliver[^:]+:` instead.